# How can I improve thread.sleep in Observable

Tags: observable, rx-java, thread-sleep

I want to improve the sleep inside the observable's doOnNext block.

Recommend if there is a better way.

```
Observable.from(sampleList)
                .buffer(5)
                .doOnNext(first -> {
                    // first Logic
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                })
                .buffer(2)
                .doOnNext(second -> {
                    // second Logic
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                })
                .buffer(2)
                .doOnNext(third -> {
                    // third Logic
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                })
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

`delay` operator is what you need

```
Observable.from(sampleList)
            .buffer(5)
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .buffer(2)
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .buffer(2)
            .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe();
```