# How to get elements from an IObservable with a delay before the start of the subscription?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to insert a 1s delay prior to the start of an `Observable` sequence, but the first record is emitted immediately upon calling `Subscribe`.  In the example below, I attempt to use RX's `Take` operator by passing a 1s `TimeSpan` and expect to receive the first string in the array delayed when I call `Subscribe`...

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<string> e = new[] { "Hi", "There", "Bye" };
    IObservable<string> strings = e.ToObservable();

    IObservable<string> stringsTimed = strings.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    stringsTimed.Trace("string");

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IDisposable Trace<T>(this IObservable<T> source, string name)
{
    return source.Subscribe
    (
        onNext: t => Console.WriteLine($"{name} -> {t}"),
        onError: ex => Console.WriteLine($"{name} ERROR: {ex.Message}"),
        onCompleted: () => Console.WriteLine($"{name} END")
    );
}
```

but when I run the program, the result of "Hi", "There", "Bye" prints on the screen immediately, without any delay, so how can I add 1 sec delay before receiving the first element "Hi"?

Comment: 'Takes elements for the specified ...' - sounds as if it would take elements for n sekonds from it and then stop regardless if there are still elements not consumed .... nothing hints at having a Sleep between elements. Beside that : Console output _can_ be cached and happens whenever - not on every "WriteLine()" command. Look up Thread.Sleep and Console.Out.Flush to manually do things - I personally hate being fed text at intervalls, but I am a fast reader and most "games" etc are just feeding me too slow.

Comment: [Observable.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229810(v=vs.103))  from  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62472087/7505395) in [how-can-i-improve-thread-sleep-in-observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440707/how-can-i-improve-thread-sleep-in-observable) is probably more along what you need

Comment: @PatrickArtner but what is the usage of Observable.Take?

Comment: You have a source that produces elements every 100ms - you "take for 2 seconds"  and get 20 elements ( 20 * 100ms >= 2000ms = 2s) - the remainder of elements genrerated after 2s is ignored.

Comment: @PatrickArtner - the OP is asking how to insert a delay before the start of the subscription.  whoisit's attempt to use `Take` as described in the post confused the matter.  `Take` is irrelevant to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take does not delay the subscription.  The `TimeSpan` overload of `Take` sets the duration the observable will observe/take records before continuing.

Try the code below.  If you want to use the extension method from your post (as opposed to the RX `Subscribe` extension method below) - put a semicolon after `DelaySubscription`...

```
string name = "Sample";
IEnumerable<string> e = new[] { "Hi", "There", "Bye" };

e.ToObservable()
    .DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
    .Subscribe( onNext: t => Console.WriteLine($"{name} -> {t}"),
                onError: ex => Console.WriteLine($"{name} ERROR: {ex.Message}"),
                onCompleted: () => Console.WriteLine($"{name} END"));
```

Comment: could you also have a look at this IObservable question?many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385578/how-to-make-error-handling-more-efficient-when-using-iobservable

Answer (score 1):

You use `Delay` on the source:

```cs
var strings = e.ToObservable().Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
```

If you want to simulate messages incoming once per second for testing purposes you can do something like the following:

```cs
string[] e = { "Hi", "There", "Bye" };
var strings = Observable.Generate(
    0,
    i => i < e.Length,
    i => i + 1,
    i => e[i],
    i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
);

Trace(strings, "timed");
Thread.Sleep(3000);

static IDisposable Trace<T>(IObservable<T> source, string name)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    return source.Subscribe
    (
        onNext: t => Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}: {name} -> {t}"),
        onError: ex => Console.WriteLine($"{name} ERROR: {ex.Message}"),
        onCompleted: () =>
        {
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}: {name} END");
        });
}
```

Comment: but what is the usage of `Observable.Take`?

Comment: @whoisit it will monitor the incoming data for specified amount of time. I.e. it will take all the elements which will come  in the provided window (which is all in your case).

Comment: @whoisit try putting `.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))` before and after `DelaySubscription` in my post to see what GuruStron is explaining firsthand

Comment: @Guru Stron,  could you also have a look at this IObservable question?many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385578/how-to-make-error-handling-more-efficient-when-using-iobservable